# FPDF - Oversized Word Spacing Issue Using MultiCell()

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using the function `GetStringWidth()` to calculate how many lines I need for a `MultiCell()`.

The column width is `75` and the result of `GetStringWidth()` is `212`, therefore 3 lines are required for my text to fit into my `MultiCell()` adequately.

The issue is that the output of this string when using `MultiCell()` is spanning over 4 lines. I then realised that this is probably because the word spacing is oversized for this string within the output, but there is no reason that this should be happening.

See the word spacing below when the string is output using `MultiCell()` (you can see the normal word spacing in the headers above):

[image]

This is the output when I tested with the same string using the `Cell()` function (ignore the formatting). The difference is noticeable:

[image]

It looks to be that either `GetStringWidth()` doesn't compare correctly with `MultiCell()` or that `MultiCell()` has a larger word spacing than `Cell()`.

I've tried with multiple fonts so I can confirm that this isn't a font specific issue.

Can anybody help me identify why this could possible be happening? My code is below. Thank you.

```
<?php
    require('fpdf.php');

    $client = new SoapClient('*API URL*');
    $session_id = $client->login('*API Username*', '*API Password*');
    $order_number = '1000000007';

    try {
        $result = $client->salesOrderInfo($session_id, $order_number);
        $products = (array) $result->items;

        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        /* Title - Company Name */
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',22);
        $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Hammer Nutrition',0,1,'C');
        /* Sub-Title - "Picking List */
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',16);
        $pdf->Cell(0,5,'Picking List',0,1,'C');
        $pdf->Ln(15);
        /* Order Number */
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',14);
        $pdf->Cell(40,5,'Order Number: ');
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);
        $pdf->Cell(40,5,$result->increment_id);
        $pdf->Ln(9);
        /* Order Creation Date */
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',14);
        $pdf->Cell(40,5,'Order Created: ');
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);
        $pdf->Cell(40,5,$result->created_at);
        $pdf->Ln(9);
        /* Shipping Name */
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',14);
        $pdf->Cell(42,5,'Shipping Name: ');
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);
        $pdf->Cell(42,5,$result->shipping_address->firstname . ' ' . $result->shipping_address->lastname);
        $pdf->Ln(9);
        /* Order Items */
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',14);
        $pdf->Cell(32,5,'Order Items: ');
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);
        $pdf->Cell(32,5,count($products));
        $pdf->Ln(9);
        /* Order Weight */
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',14);
        $pdf->Cell(35,5,'Order Weight: ');
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',14);
        $pdf->Cell(35,5,$result->weight + 0);
        $pdf->Ln(15);
        /* Order Items */
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',12);
        $pdf->Cell(17,8,' Item #',1);
        $pdf->Cell(22,8,' Line Qty',1);
        $pdf->Cell(29,8,' Line Weight',1);
        $pdf->Cell(48,8,' Product SKU',1);
        $pdf->Cell(75,8,' Product Name',1);
        $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','',11);
        $pdf->Ln(8);
        for ($i = 0, $c = count($products); $i < $c; $i++) {

            $sku_string_width = $pdf->GetStringWidth($products[$i]->sku);
            $name_string_width = $pdf->GetStringWidth($products[$i]->name);

            $sku_column_width = 48;
            $name_column_width = 75;

            $sku_number_of_lines = $sku_string_width / ($sku_column_width - 1);
            $name_number_of_lines = $name_string_width / ($name_column_width - 1);

            $number_of_lines = ceil(max($sku_number_of_lines, $name_number_of_lines));

            $standard_height_of_cells = 7;
            $height_of_cells = $number_of_lines * $standard_height_of_cells; 
            $height_of_cells = ceil($height_of_cells);

            /* Item Number */
            $pdf->Cell(17,$height_of_cells,$i + 1,1);
            /* Line Quantity */
            $pdf->Cell(22,$height_of_cells,$products[$i]->qty_ordered + 0,1);
            /* Line Weight */
            $pdf->Cell(29,$height_of_cells,$products[$i]->row_weight + 0,1);
            /* Product SKU */
            $current_y = $pdf->GetY();
            $current_x = $pdf->GetX();
            $pdf->MultiCell($sku_column_width,$standard_height_of_cells,$products[$i]->sku,1);
            $end_y = $pdf->GetY();
            /* Product Name */
            $current_x = $current_x + $sku_column_width;
            $pdf->SetXY($current_x, $current_y); 
            $pdf->MultiCell($name_column_width,$standard_height_of_cells,$products[$i]->name,1);
            $end_y = ($pdf->GetY() > $end_y)?$pdf->GetY() : $end_y;

        }

        /* Output PDF - "Picking List" */
        $pdf->Output('D',$order_number . '_picking_list.pdf');

    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        echo 'Error: ', $e->getMessage(), '<hr>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question at all, only a hint: I switched from fpdf to tcpdf and I am happy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How easy would it be for me to convert? I'm quite new to PHP and spent quite some time on this script so wouldn't want to have to start over from scratch.

Comment: It doesn't point to your PHP-skills. If you manage FPDF, as far I can see, you will TCPDF as well (or easier). TCPDF is more modern and (for me) easier to handle.

Comment: Okay thanks. If I don't get a solution here then I'll convert - but as this is the last problem before my project is finished then it would be a waste of time to do so.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Out-of-FPDF-MPDF-TCPDF-which-is-the-best-one-to-generate-a-PDF-from-text-in-PHP good luck with your project.